# WebRTC solution for direct video calls with JS

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs, videocall

I am searching for a WebRTC video call solution for Javascript, which allows direct calling between the participants and does not use rooms in between.

I checked out PeerJS, but the open issues makes me feel that it is unstable.

Now i am looking for another solution like a good open source SDK or a SDK offered by a company. Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't want separate participats in differents rooms why not create a "super room" and put all together?

Comment: if it is possible to make an invite to the super room, which would be equivalent to a call, this would be a way to go

Comment: Yes, you can use any webrtc project whose creation of rooms, just create a single room and all participants will be there. But keep in mind that rooms are an efficient way to separate specific groups of interests, you can serve many purposes with a single server.